# How can I debug over-release crashes during autorelease pool termination?

Tags: ios, memory-management, crash, automatic-ref-counting

My code grabs onto the current runloop and runs it continually (to allow UI interaction) while a much longer procedure occurs asynchronously.

This longer procedure may end up creating a lot of Objective-C objects and I believe even binding some of them into Core Foundation structures for usage with Core Foundation based API's.  We use an autorelease pool around the loop body to clean up any objects from each execution of the loop body.

I'm running into a crash at the end of the autorelease pool, which means that some ARC object probably was probably bridged to a CF API that released the object.  When the autorelease pool ends, it most likely tries to free that object.

However since it occurs at the end of the autorelease pool, I have no method of finding the culprit code.  Are there known methods of debugging such a scenario in Objective-C on iOS?

```
for(NSString *runLoopMode in (__bridge NSArray *)allCurrentRunLoopModes)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        CFRunLoopRunInMode((__bridge CFStringRef)runLoopMode,RUNLOOP_INTERVAL_SECONDS,false);
    } // <- Crash occurs here, when autorelease pool releases objects.
}
```

Comment: You have more courage than I do. I don't dare touching the run loop. I also have never had any need to do this while something was running asynchronously.

Comment: Have you tried turning on zombie objects? Edit the scheme and go to *Diagnostics* and choose *Enable Zombie Objects*. This creates a zombie object when something has been released and then has a message passed to it. You'll get a message in the debugger explaining what the object was.

Comment: Yes I have enabled zombies and run the binary in the profiler.  The app still crashes but I don't see any error messages.  No flags in the profiler show messages to a dead object.  I've isolated the entry point to the code that causes the crash to occur later during the autorelease pool drain.  It's too much to post, but I'll try to get a generalized version of it posted after the weekend.  I feel like it's something to do with a bad bridge somewhere.  But it's tough to tell when the app crashes this way, there's no stack trace because that stack already ended.